# Reading in local GeoJSON file for OpenLayers

Tags: geojson, openlayers

I am kinda new to OpenLayers and not *(yet)* very experienced in JavaScript.

I have a WordPress blog and I want to replicate and adjust the following script to my needs: http://jsfiddle.net/eqsrnjos/1/

With one big exception: I need to load the GeoJSON file from the server instead of defining it in the top (so replace the `var geoJson`).

However the most straight forward way does not seem to work for me:

```
function getData() {
return jQuery.getJSON("/json/studyCentroids.json");
}

var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures( getData() );
```

In Firebug I can see that the GeoJSON file is properly loaded, but it does not seem to appear for some reason?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), getJSON is asynchronous. You probably need a callback function.

Comment: Can you give me a short example of how such a function might look like? Pretty new to javascripting ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: 'http://yourserver.com/yourgeojsonfile.js'
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
            radius: 20,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffff00'
            })
        }))
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/9hnjok8n/

Comment: How would access the properties of that geojson file?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case: an asynchronous method is one that returns immediately while the actual work continues in the background. This allows your program to continue to run while the request, which may take a long time, is blocking. In JavaScript, you usually pass in a function that will get called when the asynchronous task completes.

In your case, `getData` is returning the return value of `getJSON` which appears to be nothing, and you're passing that value (nothing) into `readFeatures`.

Instead, you want to wait until `getJSON` succeeds, *then* call `readFeatures`:

```
var features;
jQuery.getJSON("/json/studyCentroids.json", function(data) {
  features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures( data );    
  alert(features); // success!
});
alert(features); // undefined
```

I put the alerts in there to show when you can use the features variable and when you can't.

Note: I haven't used jQuery for this, nor tested the snippet.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation! Didn't know about those asynchronous tasks before. Nevertheless I will accept @Thomas-b answer as his solutions works out of the box.

Comment: No worries. The other answer is definitely better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way of loading the geoJSON directly when creating the ol.layer.Vector object:

```
function createLayerCountries() {
    return new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            //url: 'http://www.yourserver.com/static/countries.geojson',
            url: './countries.geojson',
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
        })
    });
}
```

url supports both remote and local files, the active line takes the geojson file from the same folder the page code is.

Comment: How to to on windows path?